# Couchbase data modeling

Tags: database-design, nosql, couchbase

I come from the Relational DB world (SQL), and I'm getting started with NoSQL. So please consider that when answering.

I have two Buckets: Apps and Users.

A user may be subscribed to N applications, and every app may have M subscribers. To model that I just thought about adding a subscribed apps collection to Users like this:

```
{
    "id": "user:1",
    "apps": [
        "app:138",
        "app:16"
    ]
}
```

The issue is that I need to be able to efficiently create a list of AppsByUser (which is just user.apps) and a list of UsersByApp (which could be a view with MapReduce). If I do so, I will have a list of references to the other bucket, but no info at all, and I'll need to make one get for each "row" in the list displayed... losing all the performance gain.

How can I solve it?

Comment: By "RDB", do you mean "Relational Database" or do you mean the Oracle database product?

Comment: Relational Database, exuse me.